# (Absolute) convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1+k}{k^2-2k-\pi}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

We want to find out if the following series converges (absolutely).

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1+k}{k^2-2k-\pi}$$

Since we have $(-1)^k$, we can use the Leibniz criterion.

We have to prove that $a_n$ is a null sequence and that it is monotonically decreasing.

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1+k}{k^2-2k-\pi} \\ 
= \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^2 \cdot (\frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{k})}{k^2 \cdot (1 - \frac{2}{k} - \frac{\pi}{k^2})} \\
= \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{0}{1} = 0$$

To prove that it is monotonous decreasing, we have to show $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$

$$a_n \geq a_{n+1} 
\\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{1+k}{k^2-2k-\pi} \geq \frac{2+k}{(k+1)^2-2(k+1)-\pi} 
\\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{1+k}{k^2-2k-\pi} \geq \frac{2+k}{k^2+2k+2-2k-2-\pi}
\\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{1+k}{k^2-2k-\pi} \geq \frac{2+k}{k^2-\pi}$$

But how do we continue from here?

Comment: You can avoid verifying the monotonicity property of $(1+k)/(k^2-2k-\pi).$ See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test if it is absolutely convergent, then you need to test the following:

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+k}{k^2-2k-\pi}>\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k} \rightarrow\infty $$

So it is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get to $\frac{k}{k^2}$?

Comment: numerator: $k+1>k$ , denominator: $k^2-2k-\pi<k^2$, after you take reciprocal, then flip the direction, it becomes $\frac{1}{k^2-2k-\pi}>\frac{1}{k^2}$ hence get the desired form @user1234567890

Answer (score 1):

The Leibniz criteria only gives us conditional convergence. The series is not absolutely convergence, try the comparison criteria with $\frac{1}{k}$

Answer (score 0):

There is a general rule if $\sum a_n,$ $\sum b_n$ are convergent, and $$\sum|a_n|=\infty,\qquad \sum|b_n|<\infty$$ then $$\sum (a_n+b_n) \ {\rm is \ convergent,} \quad\sum |a_n+b_n|=\infty$$ In your case $$a_n={(-1)^n\over n}\qquad b_n=(-1)^n{1+n\over n^2-2n-\pi}-{(-1)^n\over n}$$
and $|b_n|\approx {3\over n^2}.$
Observe that we avoid verifying the monotonicity property of ${1+n\over n^2-2n-\pi}$.

In this way we decide about convergence and absolute convergence simultaneously.